# Django-Site doesn't display pictures uploaded with Django admin (ImageField) + Pillow

Tags: html, django, django-admin, python-imaging-library

Site is unable to see neither pictures uploaded by Django admin + Pillow in ImageField, neither static picture, images located in folder media/products/ in app "shop":

```
    Not Found: /media/products/no_image.png{% else %}/static/img/no_image.png
[29/Feb/2020 19:35:55] "GET /media/products/no_image.png%7B%%20else%20%%7D/static/img/no_image.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1929
```

Media/Static in settings file :

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Responsible part in List.html :

```
<div class="item">
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% 
                    else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
                </a>
```

Responsible part  in Detail.html :

```
<div class="product-detail">
        <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
        <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
        <h2><a href="{{ product.category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.category }}</a></h2>
        <p class="price">${{ product.price }}</p>
        {{ product.description|linebreaks }}
    </div>
```

Used : Django 3.0.3 , Pillow 7.0.0

Comment: `/media/products/no_image.png{% else %}/static/img/no_image.png` - some of your templates is broken - see `%{ else %}` inside the url? And please do not post extra information not related to the question: models, views, admin views have nothing to do with static or media files. Also please check indentation in your code. If it is similar to indentation in this post then your model definitions are broken.

Comment: And please define `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings.py